# JavaScript Worker : how to check if a message was received while running expensive task

Tags: javascript, dom-events, worker

I have a very expensive task running on a Worker, similar as this

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    //operations using i...
```

How can I make is so that, in that loop, I can check if a message was received from the Worker owner asking it to stop? I would like to have something like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    if(windowDidNotAskToStop())
        //operations using i...
```

Right now I have a `onmessage` function registered so I can start listen to message coming from the owner, but it is blocked while my loop is running (obviously).

I imagine that the `postMessage` calls from the owner are queued somewhere, so I would simply have to access that in order to process the calls from inside my loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll have to handle the events as usual and set a flag, but make sure to leave time for the event to be received in your loop, probably using `setTimeout`:

```
var exitLoop = false;

(function loop(i) {
    if (exitLoop || i >= 1000000000) {
        return;
    }

    // …

    setTimeout(function () {
        loop(i + 1);
    }, 0);
})(0);

onmessage = function (e) {
    if (e.data === 'stop') {
        exitLoop = true;
    }
};
```

Or, as a general utility function:

```
function asyncIterateRange(start, end, callback) {
    var exitLoop = false;
    var doneCallbacks = [];

    (function loop(i) {
        if (exitLoop) {
            return;
        }

        if (i >= end) {
            doneCallbacks.forEach(function (callback) {
                callback();
            });

            return;
        }

        callback(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                loop(i + 1);
            }, 0);
        });
    })(start);

    return {
        abort: function abort() {
            exitLoop = true;
        },
        done: function addDoneCallback(callback) {
            doneCallbacks.push(callback);
        }
    };
}
```

Use it like so:

```
var innerIterator;
var outerIterator = asyncIterateRange(0, 1000000, function outerLoop(next) {
    innerIterator = asyncIterateRange(0, 1000, function innerLoop(next) {
        // …
        next();
    }).done(next);
});

// To stop:
if (innerIterator) {
    innerIterator.abort();
}

outerIterator.abort();
```

Comment: I'm afraid this would affect my performance (I'll try it). Do you know about some other method, such as directly accessing the calls queue instead of waiting for them?

Comment: @Olivier: No. As far as I know, there’s no such thing. Keep in mind that you can terminate a worker without its event loop being freed up by calling `abort()`.

Comment: I'm still trying to work with this. I have multiple nested loops so I'm not so sure how to implement it in the innermost one. For the alternative, I'll have to see if calling abort() and recreating workers is expensive.

Comment: @Olivier: Try this utility! It might work. Also, yes, it’s expensive to do that, but whether it’s too expensive depends on what sort of situation you’ll send the stop signal in.